# cmake installation on aix installed but command not found

Tags: cmake, aix

i installed cmake on my AIX 7.2

```
bash-3.2# yum install cmake
Setting up Install Process
Package cmake-3.16.0-2.ppc already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
bash-3.2#
```

but running it .

```
bash-3.2$ cmake
bash: cmake: command not found
```

there is also no folder for cmake in /opt/bin directory

Answer (score 2):

The RPM's on AIX likely install software to /opt/freeware so you probably need /opt/freeware/bin in your PATH to casually use "cmake" on the command line.

You can verify the paths installed by a package with e.g.

```
 rpm -ql cmake|grep bin/
```